# Wrapping DIVs with inline-block

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-draggable

I want my page to look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yuA5Q/3/embedded/result

However, I am implementing jQuery ui to utilize the draggable(and sortable) functionality.  So if I don't make `.bubblescontainer` `display: inline-block`, I get some horrible effects on dragging.  however, with it, I get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yuA5Q/4/embedded/result

So, is there a way to keep the inline-block while wrapping the bubbles as desired?

---

Updated jsfiddle.net links.  I missed the final }); in the code so it wasn't running.

Comment: It would be helpful if your fiddle was set up with draggable working.

Comment: Why do blocks need to be inline to be dragged? Need more context...

Comment: inline-block causes the containing div's to grow, it seems.  Use the second link and drag the bottom bubble in the left column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by floating the internal containers (.bubblecontainer) left, and clearing left.

```
float : left;
clear : left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuA5Q/5/